# Unable to dispaly markers on map using mapbox ,leaflet Omnivore

Tags: c#, javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use CSV file to display markers on map using mapbox and leaflet. I found one example in mapbox documentation , I am trying to use the same example , I just changed the CSV file but it is not displaying markers on map. I just started using map box so desperately looking for some help.

my CSV file looks like this

Value,FacTy,Latitude,Longitude
1,112,42.27426,-83.365717
2,113,42.274082,-83.3623
3,30,42.337196,-83.487672

Here is my code snippest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Loading markers from CSV</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>

        <div id='map'></div>

        <script>
            var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
            .setView([42.274082, -83.362300], 8);
            omnivore.csv('latlon.csv',null,L.mapbox.featureLayer()).addTo(map);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a linebreak before the first row of your data. Here's [a fixed example](http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/ef89b586691d1681eb58).

```
Value,FacTy,Latitude,Longitude 1,112,42.27426,-83.365717
2,113,42.274082,-83.3623
3,30,42.337196,-83.487672
```

should be

```
Value,FacTy,Latitude,Longitude
1,112,42.27426,-83.365717
2,113,42.274082,-83.3623
3,30,42.337196,-83.487672
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what does mean by line break in CSV as I don't really see difference between above two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you, and then realized that it was a problem with the data. In order to log those errors on the console, you have to use:

```
omnivore.csv('your_file.csv', null, L.mapbox.featureLayer()).addTo(map)
  .on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And it will tell you which line is not working, such as an invalid lat or long. [More info](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#async--events).
Hope this helps!